# Javascript when callback will be called, and will it?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Let's consider following situation:
I have a function (Function1) that calls another function (Function2) and passes callback function (Function3) in.
Then it has infinite loop immediately after, to escape from which mechanism lies in callback, will callback function ever be called? How to reach `console.log('reached here');`?

```
var IamTrue = true;
function Function1() {
   Function2(Function3);
   while(IamTrue){ }
   console.log('reached here');
} 

function Function2(f3) {
   setTimeout(f3, 500);
}

function Function3() { 
   IamTrue = false; 
}
```

Comment: Did you test it? What happens?

Comment: No, because the JavaScript runtime won't interrupt the running thread. (I presume you've found this out already by simply trying your code.)

Comment: @Pointy is there a way to interrupt it?

Comment: No, at least not 'naturally' (without debugging or other manual actions). Javascript is single threaded by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript uses a single threaded run loop to execute your code; the moment your code returns it can schedule things like event handling, delayed code execution, AJAX responses, etc.

However, the code in `Function1` never ends, so the JavaScript engine never gets a chance to schedule the execution of `Function2` and thus "nothing happens".